# Regex for replacaing a custom pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regex for replacing following pattern [|E14L0] from this sample string
kindly help

```
cash|E14L0^7.0,cash|E14L2^7.0,cash|E14L1^7.0,receivables^107.0,cash|E14L3^7.0,
```

desired output is

```
"cash"^7.0 "cash"^7.0 "cash"^7.0 "receivables"^107.0 "cash"^7.0
```

requirements all patterns **|E{digit}L{digit}** needs to be replaced with `'"'` (double quotes)
all `','` between two terms needs to be replaced with `' "'` {space double quote}

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to **match** your pattern would be `\|E\d+L\d+\^([^,]+),`, and I believe you would use it like this: `preg_replace("\\|E\\d+L\\d+\\^([^,]+),", "\"$1 \"", target_string)` - note the doubling of the backslashes in the pattern parameter.

Edit: I missed the second requirement about the spaces - added.

Answer (score 0):

You would need two replacement patterns for that:

```
echo preg_replace(['/\|E\d+L\d+/','/\b,\b/'], ['"', ' "'], $str);
```

The outcome is:

```
cash"^7.0 "cash"^7.0 "cash"^7.0 "receivables^107.0 "cash"^7.0,
```